# how to extract the value of specefic div in html with crawling in apache nutch?

Tags: parsing, solr, nutch

I do crawling with nutch 2.2 and the data that i retrieve is the metatag,how to extract the value of specefic div in html with crawling in apache nutch

Answer (score 3):

You will have to write a plugin that will extend *HtmlParseFilter* to achieve your goal.

You can use some html parser like Jsoup for this and extract URLs that you want and add them as outlinks.

Sample HtmlParseFilter implementation:-

```
        public ParseResult filter(Content content, ParseResult parseResult,
              HTMLMetaTags metaTags, DocumentFragment doc) {
                // get html content
                String htmlContent = new String(content.getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                // parse html using jsoup or any other library.
                Document document = Jsoup.parse(content.toString(),content.getUrl());
                Elements elements = document.select(<your_css_selector_query);
                // modify/select only required outlinks
                if (elements != null) {
                    Outlink outlink;
                    List<String> newLinks=new ArrayList<String>();
                    List<Outlink> outLinks=new ArrayList<Outlink>();
                    String absoluteUrl;
                    Outlink outLink;
                    for (Element element : elements){
                     absoluteUrl=element.absUrl("href");
                     if(includeLinks(absoluteUrl,value)) {
                        if(!newLinks.contains(absoluteUrl)){
                          newLinks.add(absoluteUrl);
                          outLink=new Outlink(absoluteUrl,element.text());
                          outLinks.add(outLink);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    Parse parse = parseResult.get(content.getUrl());
                    ParseStatus status = parse.getData().getStatus();
                    Title title = document.title();
                    Outlink[] newOutLinks = (Outlink[])outLinks.toArray(new Outlink[outLinks.size()]);
                    ParseData parseData = new ParseData(status, title, newOutLinks, parse.getData().getContentMeta(), parse.getData().getParseMeta());
                    parseResult.put(content.getUrl(), new ParseText(elements.text()), parseData);
                    }
                   //return parseResult with modified outlinks
                   return parseResult;
            }
```

Build new plugin using ant and add plugin in nutch-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-httpclient|<custom_plugin>|urlfilter-regex|parse-(tika|html|js|css)|index-(basic|anchor)|query-(basic|site|url)|response-(json|xml)|summary-basic|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|indexer-elastic</value>
  </property>
```

And in ***parser-plugins.xml*** you can use your custom plugin instead of default plugin used by tika by something like this :-

```
<!--
    <mimeType name="text/html">
        <plugin id="parse-html" />
    </mimeType>

        <mimeType name="application/xhtml+xml">
        <plugin id="parse-html" />
    </mimeType>
-->

    <mimeType name="text/xml">
        <plugin id="parse-tika" />
        <plugin id="feed" />
    </mimeType>

    <mimeType name="text/html">
        <plugin id="<custom_plugin>" />
    </mimeType>

                <mimeType name="application/xhtml+xml">
        <plugin id="<custom_plugin>" />
    </mimeType>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the **parsefilter** and use **Jsoup selector** to select particular div.